# whitelist allowed hosts, block everything else

Tags: google-chrome-extension

using the `chrome.declarativeWebRequest`, it is possible to execute actions if some conditions apply. The only available Condition is an Instance of `declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher` which is useful to test if the url **has some features**. I am searching for a way to test if an url **does not have some features** For instance:

```
chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onRequest.addRules([
  {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher({
        url: { hostSuffix: 'google.com' } })
    ],
    actions: [
      new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.CancelRequest()
    ]
  }
]);
```

Will block all Requests to the host `google.com`. But I am interested in a rule that does the opposite, block everything but `google.com`.

Comment: You could adapt the example in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest), in the part that says 'Using priorities to override rules': Create one rule to cancel all requests, and another rule, with higher priority, to ignore the first rule if the host is `google.com`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko That seams to be it… Thanks… If you put it into an answr I am going to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest#precedences), you can use the rules' priorities to achieve your goal: create one rule to cancel all requests and another rule, with higher priority, to ignore the first rule if the host is `google.com`.